# Making code to clean string of unwanted characters

Tags: java, string, char, character, stringbuilder

I already made all the code for it but I have some issues. Not all the invalid characters are getting removed, I was unable to pickup a pattern though. I've been trying for a long time now to figure out what is causing this and I finally decided to ask you guys to see if someone can figure it out.

Here is the char array of valid characters (All other characters will be removed from string):

`static char[] validCharsUsername ={'Q','q','W','w','E','e','R','r','T','t','Y','y','U','u','I','i','O','o','P','p','A','a','S','s','D','d','F','f','G','g','H','h','J','j','K','k','L','l','Z','z','X','x','C','c','V','v','B','b','N','n','M','m','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','0','_','-'};`

Here is the code. (`this.validChars` is refering to the array):

```
public String cleanString(String text){
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(text);
    for(int i = 0;i < sb.length() - 1;i++){
        char character = sb.charAt(i);
        int index = 0;
        char indexChar = this.validChars[0];
        boolean valid = false;
        while(index < this.validChars.length - 1){
            index++;
            indexChar = this.validChars[index];
            if(character == indexChar){
                valid = true;
                index = this.validChars.length;
            }   
        }
        if(!valid){
            if(character == ' '){
                sb.deleteCharAt(i);
                sb.insert(i, '_');
            }else{
                sb.deleteCharAt(i);
            }
            i = 0;
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: What is the exmaple input-output that doesn't work?

Comment: @Pshemo Changed it, I meant valid, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try use this code :

```
public static String cleanString(String text){
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("");
    for(int i = 0;i < text.length();i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < validCharsUsername.length; j++) {
            if (validCharsUsername[j] == text.charAt(i)) {
                sb.append(text.charAt(i));
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

**UPDATE**
Fist i think it is C# and i wrote C# Code, but now i changed it to java

Comment: Um..., this question is tagged Java. In Java, arrays don't have a `Contains` method and strings are not accessed by subscript.

Comment: text[i] is new for me too

Comment: Yea there is no contains method. Also instead of text[i] i used text.charAt(i). Does anyone else have any ideas?

Comment: Thank you for changing the code to work in java. It works flawlessly now. Here is the final code: http://pastebin.com/iGJ8Fx1r          Java should add a contains method for arrays, it will make some things easier.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe consider using [regular expressions](http://regular-expressions.info) which. Regex which will match all characters in range a-z and all digits 0-9 can look like `[a-zA-Z0-9]`. Regex which will match all characters except mentioned earlier can look like `[^a-zA-Z0-9]` so your code could look like

```
public String cleanString(String text){
    return text.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9]","");
}
```

In case you want also to let spaces or any other characters stay you can add them to this [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) and change return statement to `text.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9\\s]","");` (`\\s` represents whitespaces).

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I went with another one. This may still be useful in the future though!